# How to convert string "2019-10-09T06:07:05.888Z" as calendar date and time

Tags: r, timestamp, posixct, posixlt

Please help me to find a solution for converting "2019-10-09T06:07:05.888Z" as a calendar time stamp. I tried the following methods,

```
> format(as.POSIXlt("2019-10-09T06:07:05.888Z"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
[1] "2019-10-09 00:00:00.000"

> as.POSIXct("2019-10-09T06:07:05.888Z", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `as.POSIXct`, we can first convert the data into `POSIXct` class and then use `format` to display the output in the format we want.

```
temp <- as.POSIXct("2019-10-09T06:07:05.888Z",format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC")
format(temp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
#[1] "2019-10-09 06:07:05.888"
```

Or with `lubridate`

```
format(lubridate::ymd_hms("2019-10-09T06:07:05.888Z"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I need the millisecond information too. Is there any option in format ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `options(digits.secs = 3)` above `as.POSIXct()` for getting the exact calendar format.

```
> options(digits.secs = 3)
> as.POSIXct("2019-10-09T06:07:05.888Z",format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC")
[1] "2019-10-09 06:07:05.888 UTC"
```